# How to merge Stream<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> into a single Map<String, Map<String, String>>?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to merge a `Stream<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>` object into a single map with keys in all the `Streams`.

For example,

```
final Map<String, someOtherObjectToProcess> someObject;

final List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> list = someObject.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(this::getInfoStream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The signature for getInfoStream is

```
public Stream<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> getInfoStream(Map.Entry<String, someOtherObjectToProcess> entry)
```

if I use `(Collectors.toList())` I am able to get a list of these Map objects.

Sample output if I use the above code:

```
[{
    "name" : {
        "property":"value"
    }
},

{
    "name2" : {
        "property":"value"
    }
}]
```

But I want to collect into a Map with the structure

```
{
    "name" : {
        "property":"value"
    },
    "name2" : {
        "property":"value"
    }
}
```

Provided that the keys will be unique.

**How can I do this with Collectors.toMap() or any other alternative way?**

Comment: show the signature of `getInfoStream` and what `someObject` looks like, please

Comment: for some reason, it seems like the cause of the problem would be the implementation of `getInfoStream` which is returning a `Stream<Map<>>` and not even `Stream<Map.Entry>`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have

```
Stream<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> stream = ...
```

(which I am assuming is result of `.flatMap(this::getInfoStream)`) you can call

```
.flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
```

to create stream of entries from all maps which will produce `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>>>`.

Now from that stream all you need to do is *collect* key and value from each entry into map. Assuming each key will be unique across all maps you could use

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

but if keys are not unique you need to decide what value should be placed in new map for same key. We can do it by filling `...` part in

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (vOld, vNew) -> ...));
//                                                                                ^^^
```

where `vOld` holds value currently held in result map under same key, and `vNew` holds new value (from current stream "iteration").
For instance if you want to ignore new value you can simply return old/currently held by `(vOld, vNew) -> vOld`

So in short (assuming unique keys):

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> combinedMap = 
        /*your Stream<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>*/
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: In my case, the maps keys are unique and updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this would be not using a `collector(toList())` but the other overloaded `.collect()` method with Supplier, Accumulator, and Combiner:

```
Stream<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> stream = ...
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = stream
       .collect(HashMap::new, HashMap::putAll, HashMap::putAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most readable way in my opinion is to map everything to a `Map.Entry` and then collect everything back to a `Map` using `Collectors::toMap`

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

// ...

someObject.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .flatMap(this::getInfoStream)
          .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
          .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (one, two) -> one));
```

`(one, two) -> one` is the merge function, basically if you have duplicates, you just arbitrarely take the first one to come up

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

```
var merged = Stream.of(map1, map2, ..., mapN).reduce(new HashMap<>(), (a, b) -> {
    a.putAll(b);
    return a;
});
```

---

You can use `reduce` to combine a stream of `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` elements into one:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        alternative1();
        alternative2();
    }

    // Use reduce without an initial identity value
    public static void alternative1() {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> m1 = new HashMap<>();
        m1.put("name", Map.of("property", "value"));

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> m2 = new HashMap<>();
        m2.put("name2", Map.of("property", "value"));

        Stream<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> mapStream = Stream.of(m1, m2);

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> m3 = mapStream.reduce((a, b) -> {
            Map<String, Map<String, String>> temp = new HashMap<>();
            temp.putAll(a);
            temp.putAll(b);
            return temp;
        }).orElseThrow();

        System.out.println(m3);
    }

    // Use reduce with an initial empty map as the identity value
    public static void alternative2() {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> m1 = new HashMap<>();
        m1.put("name", Map.of("property", "value"));

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> m2 = new HashMap<>();
        m2.put("name2", Map.of("property", "value"));

        Stream<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> mapStream = Stream.of(m1, m2);

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> m3 = mapStream.reduce(new HashMap<>(), (a, b) -> {
            a.putAll(b);
            return a;
        });

        System.out.println(m3);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{name={property=value}, name2={property=value}}
{name={property=value}, name2={property=value}}
```

But beware that these solutions assume keys (`name` and `name2`) are unique, otherwise duplicate keys would make map entries overwrite each other.

---

The same logic with a more modern syntax:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        alternative1();
        alternative2();
    }

    // Use reduce without an initial identity value
    public static void alternative1() {
        var m1 = Map.of("name", Map.of("property", "value"));
        var m2 = Map.of("name2", Map.of("property", "value"));
        var m3 = Stream.of(m1, m2).reduce((a, b) -> {
            var temp = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
            temp.putAll(a);
            temp.putAll(b);
            return temp;
        }).orElseThrow();

        System.out.println(m3);
    }

    // Use reduce with an initial empty map as the identity value
    public static void alternative2() {
        var m1 = Map.of("name", Map.of("property", "value"));
        var m2 = Map.of("name2", Map.of("property", "value"));
        var m3 = Stream.of(m1, m2).reduce(new HashMap<>(), (a, b) -> {
            a.putAll(b);
            return a;
        });

        System.out.println(m3);
    }
}
```